# Power BI - how to count duplicates from two identical sets with different filters

Tags: powerbi, intersection, slicers

I have two tables which contain the same data - TableA (PersonId, ItemId, Session) and TableB(PersonId, ItemId, Session). Here is some test data:

---

```
PersonId    |  ItemId       | Session
-------------------------------------------------
1           |  1            | Summer 2017
1           |  1            | Spring 2017
2           |  1            | Summer 2017
2           |  2            | Summer 2017
3           |  5            | Spring 2017
```

There are two slicers for the different sessions (for simplicity I have only showed two in the test data but they may be a lot more). The user has to see the number of different PersonIds for the selected session in the first slicer by 
ItemId. Then there should be information on the number of PersonIds that are both present in the first and second sessions in the selected slicers.

My idea is to filter TableA by the selected value in the first slicer and then filter TableB by the selected value in the second slicer, but I am not sure how to do that dynamically? Also, I may need a third table for the intersection of filtered TableA and Filtered TableB. Do you have any ideas on how I achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Why do you have two tables with the same data?

Comment: So that I can have the filtered data by my two slicers at the same time - one slicer selected value filters the first table and the other slicer's selected value - the second. For example, I can have the data for Summer 2017 in the first table and the data for Spring 2017 in the second.

Comment: You do not need duplicate data to do this. You can control which visuals are affected by which slicers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-visualization-slicers#control-which-page-visuals-are-affected-by-slicers